# .NET MVC dropdown with dinamic data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning to use .NET MVC creating an app on Visual Studio. I'm trying to add a dropdown with dinamic data from one of my Models. The idea is that when a "project" is added, it selects one "client"(created previously) on the dropdown using the name.

My "Project" class looks as follows:

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Client { get; set; }
}
public enum Type
{
    NewProject,
    OldProject,
    InteriorDesign,
    ExteriorDesign
}
```

I was able to create a dropdwon for the type of project using the enum "Type":

```
         @Html.DropDownListFor(
                model => model.Type,
                new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Type))),
                "Type of project",
                new { @class = "form-control" }
                )
```

This is my Client class:

```
    public class Client
        {
            [Key]
            public int ClientID { get; set; }
            public string Name{ get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Project> Project{ get; set; }
        }
```

An when I try to add the dropdown, I don't manage to select the Name value to be used in the dropdwon. Something like this but I'm not sure what goes on the _____ spaces:

```
           @Html.DropDownListFor(
                model => model.Client,
                new SelectList(__________________),
                "Client name",
                new { @class = "form-control" }
                )
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You can create a static class and in your SelectList call a static method to generate the list items.  You can pass values at run time to alter the list if required.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a static class and generate the dropdown, but it doesn't show any data, even thought I already have data on the database.
This is my new static class that contains only the clients Names and IDs, I transform it into a List of items with ClientID and Name as atributes:

```
    public static class ClientList
    {
        public static Client client = new Client();
        public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients = new List<Client>
        {
            new Client {ClientID= client.ClientID,
                        Name = client.Name
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And the dropdown build on the view:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(
                    model => model.Client,
                    new SelectList(ClientList.Clients, "ClientID", "Name"),
                    "Client name",
                    new { @class = "form-control" }
                    )
```

I'm sure I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what. Do I need to add something on the crontroller part for this to work?
Thanks in advance!